# Android Lollipop LinearLayout on the bottom of the screen

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listview

I have this problem only on Lollipop, older versions work (4.0 to 4.X).

In my xml, i have 3 parts :

- First part :
  An ImageView with TextView.
- Second part :
  A ListView
- Third :
  A bottom bar with Buttons in a LinearLayout (horizontal)

Problem :
In Android Lollipop Device, the third part is missing and ListView go to end of the screen.

Theme used : Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar (to colorize the MediaRouteButton in grey)

XML Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cover"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/cover"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/default_cover" />

            And other stuff...

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="15.0sp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#f0f0f0"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/img1" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:gravity="center">

                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/bar_vol"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/img2" />

                <android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton
                    android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:showAsAction="always"
                    android:title="Cast" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Do you have an idea of where the problem is ?

Comment: i think the problem is with "android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton" try reinstalling the support library

Comment: same without MediaRouteButton, the LinearLayout won't appear

Comment: If it only happens on Lollipop, I can imagine it is caused by the theme. Have you tried a different theme or no theme at all?

Comment: Yes, only on Lollipop, i have tried with some themes :
- AppCompat.Light = not work
- Material.Light = not work
- Holo = work but the MediaRouteButton is white and my background is white too

Comment: My first instinct is there are too many LinearLayouts, makes it hard to visualize. I think you can easily remove LinearLayout which has only one UI element in it, like the one with ImageView. I'll post an answer to something else though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem !
In fact, the LinearLayout was behind the navigationBar. To fix it, just add this line to the Activity (after setContentView();) :

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom LinearLayout where `android:weightSum="10"`, this is the sum of all the `android:layout_weight` of the children UI elements.
So...one LinearLayout (that contains SeekBar) has all the weight `layout_weight="10"`. This could impact the other UI elements and make them not visible.

Another, the parent layout with the weightSum is horizontal (android`:orientation="horizontal"`), this means the children should have android`:layout_width="0dp"`. Otherwise they are conflicting with unpredictable results. It's like if you want to get benefits of weight calculations (and I like it too), don't specify the size too.

Depending on how things progress with my day, this post, and your response, I might download your layout xml for me to experiment. I plan to get a Master degree on layouts since it is important.

If you can, remove the extraneous LinearLayouts as I mentioned in my comment above. This can make your life easier. Otherwise debugging this layout may mean "an all-nighter".